# removeClass and addClass don't work

Tags: select, tabs, addclass, removeclass

i have a statement that checks if a tab is selected:

```
$( '#social_edit_pannels' ).tabs({
select: function(event, ui) { 
var theSelectedTab = ui.index;

if (theSelectedTab  == 0) {
$('ul li.ep-messages').removeClass('ep-messages').addClass('ep-messages-click');
$('ul li.ep-friends').removeClass('ep-friends-click').addClass('ep-friends');
}
else if (theSelectedTab  == 1 ) {
$('ul li.ep-friends').removeClass('ep-friends').addClass('ep-friends-click');
$('ul li.ep-messages').removeClass('ep-messages-click').addClass('ep-messages');
}
   }
});
```

What is happening is that only the first statement of remove'ing and adding classes works from each if statement.

for example when i run the script, it behaves like it would have only this:

```
if (theSelectedTab  == 0) {
$('ul li.ep-messages').removeClass('ep-messages').addClass('ep-messages-click');
}
else if (theSelectedTab  == 1 ) {
$('ul li.ep-friends').removeClass('ep-friends').addClass('ep-friends-click');
}
```

the second statement from each if... doesn't work.
maybe it doesn't know if the classes are there??

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul li.ep-friends').removeClass('ep-friends-click').addClass('ep-friends');
```

`$('ul li.ep-friends')` does not have yet `ep-friends` class, that's why it's not found
you have to use another selector instead of `'ul li.ep-friends'`

same explanation for 2nd one.

Comment: great observation, i found i way using .hasClass